# AWS - Serverless - "message": "Internal server error" when deploying, but work offline

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a problem when deploying a project using Serverless framework and Amazon Web Services (more specifically API Gateway service).

On my local machine, when I do `serverless offline` everything works fine:
When going to `http://localhost:3000/`, I have:

```
{
    "message": "welcome"
}
```

When navigating to `http://localhost:3000/examples`, I have:

```
{
    "message": "Example test"
}
```

However, when deploying with `serverless deploy`, only the first one works. The next one displays the following:

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

In my code I have the following routes:

```
app.use('/examples', ExampleController)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({
    message: 'welcome'
  })
})
```

And this is what I have in my ExampleController:

```
ExampleController.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({
    message: 'Example test'
  })
})
```

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you provide the CloudWatch log that helps a lot on debugging issues likes this?

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first one works"? And as @KaHouIeong has already mentioned, look at the CloudWatch logs.

Comment: Fixed the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my problem by adding the following role in iamRoleStatements in serverless.yml:

```
-  Effect: "Allow"
   Action:
     - "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource"
   Resource: "*"
```